# How can you transfer specific keys from one bundle to another?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using the Activity as a controller and Fragments as views method to create my application.

Communications between them is implemented with Bundles, as in I pass a Bundle at the fragment creation which is then stored as the arguments of the fragment and the fragment updates itself using that bundle's information

I also created the method

```
public void update(Bundle data)
```

which is where the update happens and is called by onCreateView as well as the activity when it wishes to alter the state of the fragment.

Now since I wish (if there is a need to recreate the fragment) to save the current state of the fragment, I decided that the base method of update(bundle) should copy all values related to the current fragment to the arguments.

Unfortunatelly I can't find a method other than putAll to copy directly data from one bundle (the parameter of the update method) to another ( the arguments of the fragment), and I do not wish to use putall because the bundle may contain data that I do not wish to save in the bundle arguments, I only wish to copy values for the keys that already exist

is there any way to do this?

Comment: you should use interface class as bridge to communicate between activity and fragment without recreate the activity or fragment

Comment: I do use one, when the fragment sends requests , it uses the interface that is implemented by the activity, and when I wish to update the fragment with data from the activity I have the ICoreView interface which has the void update(Bundle) method, so the activity casts the currently showing fragment to ICoreView and sends the update message